# Arduino Editor: Monitor menu show "Serial port unavailable"

Tags: serial, communication, atmega328, ubuntu

Ubuntu 16.04LTS 64bit, Arduino Pro Mini board (ATmega 328P, 3.3V 8Mhz)
I have problem with WEB editor: I selected Arduino Pro mini and ticked "8Mhz ATmega 328P". I tried to upload "blink" test program from Examples, but Web editor show "Error uploading, check if selected board is currently available." And Monitor menu show "Serial port unavalable".

```
$ dmesg | grep tty
[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
```

I tried to reboot, not help. The green LED on Arduiono is "on" and red LED is blinking. I tried to verify the built-in COM port, in terminal run command    `dmesg | grep FTDI`, but no any output returned.

```
$ ls -l /dev/ttyUSB*
ls: cannot access '/dev/ttyUSB*': No such file or directory
```

It looks that FTDI USB to Serial port converter not recognized on Ubuntu?

Comment: I've had this in Windows before now. There, I was able to resolve it by reinstalling the driver from device manager. I don't have an Ubuntu box with me so can't test the steps for Ubuntu yet. I'll try later, but let me know if this works in the meantime.

Comment: This [guide](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ftdi-drivers/linux) was for Ubuntu 13.04. I'm working from a mobile phone screen, so I couldn't find a more current guide.

Comment: What are you uploading through? The Pro Mini has no USB interface of its own.

Comment: Mini Pro connected via FTDI USB to Serial converter Breakout (FT232RL).

Comment: I believe, the FTDI drivers already have been built in Ubuntu, not?

Comment: Have you tried a different cable?

Comment: Tried another cable, FTDI adapter now recognized, `$ ls -l /dev/ttyUSB*` return
`crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 Aug 26 19:45 /dev/ttyUSB0`. But Serial port is still grayed out.

Comment: And have you added yourself to the dialout group as per the Linux Arudino instructions?

Comment: I missed that, after adding user to the group 'dialout', the serial port is now enabled. `sudo usermod -a -G dialout username`. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

type "tail -f /var/log/kern.log" into a terminal window. This will show you the messages that the kernel produces. Hit enter a few times so you can easily see when something new is added.

Now remove (hmm. easier if you do that before typing the command above).  and insert the arduino. Now your kernel should produce a few messages stating it found a new device. Linux has drivers for all popular USB chips so no driver issues expected.

With a bit of luck you'll see something like: 
   Aug 27 18:53:23 kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver ch341
   Aug 27 18:53:23 kernel: usb 3-3: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB0
What comes after "now attached to" is what you need to use for the serial port....

Answer (score 1):

Do a `ls -l /dev/tty*` in a console screen and then search for the tty* port that your arduino is connected to (mine is `ttyACM0`), you will see which group (my group is `dialout` for Ubuntu 17.10) you need to add yourself to in order to be able to access your arduino via the Serial Monitor.